# Problem when Updating value (PUT) in ASP.NET core ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm currently learning ASP.NET Core and having some problem. Basically, I have a model like this:

```
public class WorkRoom
{
[Key]
public int WorkRoomId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Room")]
[Required]
public int RoomId { get; set; }
public Room Room { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Employee")]
[Required]
public string Id { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser Employee { get; set; }
}
```

and a Dto for this model cause i only want to pass two value is RoomId and Id(using identityUser).
**WorkRoomDto.cs**

```
public class WorkRoomDto
{
public int RoomId { get; set; }
public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can write POST, GET and DELETE method normally as i wish, but I have some problems writing PUT.

```
        public async Task<Response> PutWorkRooms(int id, WorkRoomDto workRoom)
        {
            var respone = new Response();
            var workRoomId = _context.WorkRooms.Any(i => i.WorkRoomId == id);
            var userId = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(workRoom.Id);
            if (workRoomId)
            {
                if (userId == null)
                {
                    respone.Status = false;
                    respone.Message = "User not exist";
                    return respone;
                }
                var newWorkRoom = mapper.Map<WorkRoomDto, WorkRoom>(workRoom);
                _context.Entry(newWorkRoom).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                respone.Status = true;
                respone.Message = "Successfully updated.";
                respone.Data = workRoom;
            }
            else
            {

                respone.Status = false;
                respone.Message = "WorkRoomId no exist.";
            }
            return respone;
        }
```

But it showed ***Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).***

Before the autoMappter I had tried

```
_context.Entry(workRoom).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But it says the Dto is not in the DbContext. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @Đạt Nguyễn, any update?

Comment: Hi @Rena, sry for not updating. I had solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, `WorkRoomId` is 0 in `newWorkRoom`. You need set the value for it. Just change like below:

```
var newWorkRoom = mapper.Map<WorkRoomDto, WorkRoom>(workRoom);
newWorkRoom.WorkRoomId = id;   //add this line...
_context.Entry(newWorkRoom).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Automapper give you a brand new object that created locally (not taking back from the database), therefore, not tracked by the dbContext.

So, when you try to update `newWorkRoom` by forcing the state to modified, the dbContext know it want to see an update operation, but unfortunately, nothing got tracked, then execute nothing.

Try this

```
var newWorkRoom = mapper.Map<WorkRoomDto, WorkRoom>(workRoom);
if (_context.Entry(newWorkRoom).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    var entityFromDb = await _context.WorkRooms.FindAsync(id);
    _context.Entry(entityFromDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(newWorkRoom);
}
```

Comment: It shows "The property 'WorkRoom.WorkRoomId' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified." Is there anything more i need to add?